# Route RRAS traffic through a proxy

Tags: windows-server-2003, proxy, rras

I have a VPN server up and running on a windows server 2003. All the users are able to connect to the server and NAT their IP (use server IP and internet).

I was wondering if I could route all the traffic to a proxy server. In other words, Users connect to RRAS and then the whole traffic will go through a remote/local (127.0.0.1:4567).

Is it possible to implement? Is it right to do?

Answer (score 3):

If your proxy can also route traffic, you can just configure RRAS to route all traffic from the NAT interface to the proxy. If your proxy does not route, then you should use something like GPO to enforce proxy settings on browsers inside of your network and block outbound traffic that does not go through the proxy at your firewall.